# Shopping Cart Price Rule: Spend $X Get SKU1 or SKU2 Free NOT Counting SKU1,2 in Total Spend

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules

I've got a situation where if a user spends $40, they are eligible for either one free SKU1 or one free SKU2. The issue I am having when setting up the catalog price rule is that SKU1 or 2 in the cart is counting toward that $40.

I tried this but I think the `SKU is not` logic nullifies the action:

`If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
    Subtotal  equals or greater than  40

    If total quantity  equals or greater than 1  for a subselection of items in cart matching ANY  of these conditions: 
        SKU  is not  SKU1 
        SKU  is not  SKU2`

Any help would be nice!

Comment: I ended up resolving this by simplying changing 40+ to 40+costume price, since all it was doing was reducing the price of the costume anyway. Overthinking it.

Comment: Please add it as answer if your problem is resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up resolving this by simplying changing 40+ to 40+costume price, since all it was doing was reducing the price of the costume anyway.